# Polynominal odd function

Tags: polynomials

If $f(x$) is an odd function and $x-y$ is a factor. show that $x^2-y^2$ is a factor as well

I'm having trouble to solve this

Comment: What is $y$? If it’s a variable, I don’t see how $x-y$ can divide a polynomial without any $y$’s in it.

Comment: $x-y$ is a factor of $f(x)$?

Comment: Maybe interpret the $y$ as some constant like $a$ and it asks if $f$ odd and $x-a$ is a factor of $f$ so is $x^2-a^2.$

Comment: @coffeemath Then we need $y\neq 0$, otherwise consider $f(x)=x$

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $f(x)=p(x)$ is a polynomial that is an odd function. If $x-a$ is a factor of $p(x)$ then we can write $p(x)=(x-a)q(x).$ Since $p$ is an odd function we have

$$p(-a)=-p(a)=(a-a)q(a)=0.$$ That is, $-a$ is a root of $p(x)$ and, so, $x+a$ is a factor of $p(x).$ In consequence $x-a$ and $x+a$ are factors of $p(x),$ from where we get that $(x-a)(x+a)$ is a factor of $p(x).$